# Calculating distance using latitude and longitude error

Tags: r, geosphere

I am using this code:

```
a<-c(35.929673,-78.948237)
b<-c(38.889510,-77.032000)
c<-c(38.032120,-78.477510)
d<-c(36.379450,-75.830290)
df<-data.frame(a,b,c,d)
for (i in 1:(ncol(df)))
{
   for (j in (i+1):ncol(df))  
  {

   o<-distHaversine(as.vector(df[i]),as.vector(df[j]))

    print(o)

  }

}
```

I am getting an error:

> Error in p[, 2] : subscript out of bounds

Comment: We have 4 columns, i+1 would give you 5.

Comment: something like `df<-rbind(a,b,c,d)` then `o<-geosphere::distHaversine(df)` ?